# Is it possible to prevent large files being uploaded to a server by specifying a maximum request body size?

Tags: http, cherrypy, content-length

I have a server in cherrpy where I want to prevent large files from being uploaded. To prevent this I specify a maximum request body size. However, I am not really sure if this prevents large files from being uploaded. What if someone advertises an incorrect content-length when uploading a file ? Will that be enough to trick my server ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Curl to try and test your theory.  It looks like this could work for setting a bogus content-length.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-length: 100');
```

[Curl content-length usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139709/problem-with-curl-to-send-content-length-header)

Hope this helps!

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

CherryPy will not allow the full upload in all cases. The CherryPy wsgiserver will complain if the requests' Content-Length value exceeds the maximum. If the Content-Length is less than the specified maximum, the server will only attempt to read that many bytes. If the request uses chunked encoding (and therefore does not include a Content-Length) then CherryPy will complain when the number of bytes read exceeds the specified maximum.