# Upload file using libcurl + POST and headers

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I am trying to upload a file to a webserver using libcurl (in C).  The server requires that I use POST, not PUT (which is what CURLOPT_UPLOAD would use).  I also need to send a specific token in the header.  This is what I have so far:

```
int upload(char *filepath, char *filename, char *token) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    FILE *fd;
    struct stat file_info;

    char *file;
    asprintf(&file, "%s/%s", filepath, filename);

    fd = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (!fd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get file information.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    curl = curl_easy_init()
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://127.0.0.1/upload");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:application/octet-stream");

    char *my_token = malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "X-Token:%s", token) + 1);
    sprintf(my_token, "X-Token:%s", token);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, my_token);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Upload OK.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The only response I get from the server is that it is a "400 Bad Request".

I have written code in Python that performs the same action, and this file upload works:

```
import urllib, urllib2, json, os
def upload(self, filepath, filename, token):
    # Open file
    f = open(os.path.join(filepath, filename), 'rb')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()

    request = urllib2.Request("https://127.0.0.1/upload" % filedata, {"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream", "X-Token":token})
    res = self.opener.open(request)
    return json.loads(res.read())
```

UPDATE:
After running with verbose mode:

```
> POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
X-Token: 17f684-b98c
Content-Length: -1
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 Bad Request
....
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're missing a call just before the `curl_easy_perform()` that is,

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Also, add

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE 1L);
```

to get verbose output, it can be very useful in debugging, and would likely have made your above missing headers obvious.

Edit:
You need to set the post field size `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` and may need to clear the `Expect:` header as well.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, file_info.st_size);
....
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Expect:");
```

Comment: I added both, and I am still getting 400 Bad Request.  Will edit question to include output from verbose mode.

Comment: @user2406467 Content length of -1 is concerning. I am suspect of the `CURLOPT_READDATA` actually getting the data into the POST field. Can you read the file into a buffer and then put that into curl? I've never used it like that. Can you do anything like verbose for your python solution and see where the two differ?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141147/1688185): for a `PUT` request you must explicitly set the size of the file here with: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);`.

Comment: @deltheil I can't use a PUT request.  The server is not configured to accept anything but POST (and I can't change it).

Comment: @Macattack I will try reading the file into a buffer, although admittedly, my C knowledge is shaky at best.

Comment: @user2406467: that being said, since your problem is related to the content length computation, you should try to explicitly the file size as explained above.

Comment: @deltheil You've got it, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` needs to be set to the file size as: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, file_info.st_size)`. It may also be necessary to add `Expect:` as a  header.

Comment: @user2406467 Should have addressed you in my last comment, You need to set the post field size as described above. Should at least address the `-1` content length.

Comment: @Macattack Setting the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE and attempting again makes it to a Content-Length of 8, which I'm pretty sure is incorrect.  Going to try reading into a buffer now.